# Integral of $f_n$ from $0$ to $1$ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(t)$ be defined as $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}1, \text{if}\,\,t\in[\frac{p}{2^k},\frac{p+1}{2^k})\\ 0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ where $n=2^k+p,\,\,0\le p<2^k$. Then,

a)what can be the value of $\lim\sup f_n(t)$ and $\lim\inf f_n(t)$?

b)Is $\int_0^1|f_n(t)|\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ true?

For part b), I think that as $n\to\infty$, the function approaches zero because of the constriction of the interval on which it is $1$.Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) For a fixed $t \in [0,1]$ and some time $N$, is there an $n > N$ so that $f_n(t) > 0$?

b) Write out an explicit bound to formalize your idea. What is the value of integral at the stage when the interval has length $2^{-n}$?

Bonus: Think about $b$ for the function $2^k f_n$ instead ($n = 2^k + p$). What's the difference?

Comment: i think $\lim\sup f_n(t)=1$ and $\lim\inf f_n(t)=0$, am I right in that

Comment: @vidyarthi yes you are

Comment: but, how can we fix $t$, as it is dependent on $n$, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi the limsup is over n... it is not the limit of sup over t. (probably). though the answers are numerically the same.

Comment: First fix $t=0$. Then, as $n\to\infty$, the function approaches 1, right, so integral should be 1, isnt it?

Comment: @vidyarthi I'm not sure what you are trying to answer now. What function, what integral. Why are you fixing t...

Comment: i am trying to answer part b). As $f_n(t)=1$ at $t=0$ and $n\to\infty$, will not the integral also tend to 1?

Comment: @vidyarthi No, for example the function that is 1 at 0 and 0 everywhere else. Also in general interchanging a limit and integral is subtle -- see the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.